# Umbraco - upgrade from 6.2.0 to 7.1.8

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco5, umbraco-blog

My upgrade from 6.2.0 to 7.1.8 has been largely successful.

But when I try and fix this issue in the back office of Umbraco, when I click developer > datatype folder if I click any of the datatypes under this I get this error:

```
Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'umbraco.cms.presentation.developer.editDatatype'
Source Error: 
Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="c#" MasterPageFile="../../masterpages/umbracoPage.Master" Title="Edit data type"
Line 2:      ValidateRequest="false"
Line 3:      CodeBehind="editDatatype.aspx.cs" AutoEventWireup="True" Inherits="umbraco.cms.presentation.developer.editDatatype" %>
 Source File: /umbraco/developer/datatypes/editDataType.aspx
```

So what I did was look at the file: `umbraco\Developer\DataTypes\editDatatype.aspx` on the files system.

I noticed that THIS FILE IS NOT PRESENT ON A CLEAN INSTALL OF Umbraco 7, so I deleted it, now I get a 404 when I click a data-type.

After a bit of investigation I am pretty sure the Umbraco back office is looking in the wrong place. I had a look at a clean install of 7 and it seems to be looking here: `umbraco\Views\datatype`

I think something must not been updated when I did the upgrade.

Any ideas what?

I am at the last hurdle everything else seems to work, but I just can't make changes to the datatypes.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure your .config files have been updated. I would recommend starting with looking at the datatype alias.
Umbraco 6 trees.config value:

```
<add application="developer" alias="datatype" title="Data Types" type="umbraco.loadDataTypes, umbraco" iconClosed=".sprTreeFolder" iconOpen=".sprTreeFolder_o" sortOrder="1" />
```

Umbraco 7 changed trees.config value:

```
<add initialize="true" sortOrder="0" alias="datatype" application="developer" title="Data Types" iconClosed="icon-folder" iconOpen="icon-folder" type="Umbraco.Web.Trees.DataTypeTreeController, umbraco" />
```